# Analogy between covariance of two random variables and derivative of a function.

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, reference-request

Consider a random variable $X$. Define $Y$ as an affine transformation of $X$, $Y=\alpha+\beta X$ for some $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{R}$. In this case, it holds that:
$$Cov(Y,X)=\beta Var(X)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} Var(X)$$
where $f(x)=\alpha+\beta x$ is the transformation linking $Y$ and $X$. Hence, in this case, up to a rescaling given by the variance of $X$, the covariance of $X$ and $Y$ is the derivative of the transformation linking them.

**My first question is**: In the more general case $Y=f(X)$ for a sufficiently regular $f(x)$ is there a link between the derivative function $f'(x)$ and $Cov(Y,X)$?

Secondly, for an arbitrary random vector $(X,Y)$  we can always think that realizations $(x,y)$ are obtained first sampling $x$ from the marginal distribution of $X$ and then $y$ from the conditional distribution of $Y$ given $X=x$. Hence, there is a sense in which we can see $Y$ as a transformation of $X$, through a Markov Kernel $\mu:\mathbb{R}\to\Delta(\mathbb{R})$ which maps any $x$ to the law of $Y|X=x$ (with the notation $\Delta(\mathbb{R})$ I mean the space of probability distribution on $\mathbb{R}$).

**My second question is**: In this completely arbitrary case, can we relate $Cov(Y,X)$ to some notion of derivative of the Markov Kernel $\mu$?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing some subtlety to your question, but the reason that relation holds for a linear $f$ is because taking the covariance with a variable is a linear map, and it maps a constant to 0. This easily gives the relation you say:
$$L(\alpha+\beta X)=L(\alpha)+\beta L(X)=\beta L(X)$$
For an arbitrary linear map. This is specific to linear maps, so I don't see a reason to expect there to be a version of this for nonlinear functions, short of just substituting the law of the unconscious statistician into the integral formula for covariance.

Comment: Yeah, I know that covariance is a bilinear form. And maybe there is nothing more to this. What I was thinking is along the following. Consider the case where $f$ is analytical. Then you can write it as a Taylor series (without loss, center it in $0$). Hence, you can write the covariance as a series of terms of the form $Cov(X,X^n)$ weighted by the higher order derivatives evaluated at $0$.

Comment: More intuitively, it seems to me that one thinks about covariance as how the two variables "going together". This is also how one thinks about incremental ratios.